# Mysql large db migration

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mysqlimport

Hi I'm building a enterprise management system (php based) for a medium size company.  I'm trying to migrate their existing customer records about (9000 records) into my db.  Our db schemas are different.

Here are the steps I'm planning to take:

1.) Get the .csv file for each table and clean it up (get rid of unnecessary columns, remove blanks rows which seem to be littered throughout table)

2.) Import the tables into my database via phpmyadmin

3.) Write a php script to loop grab tables with this old data and then process and insert them into MY db tables

I was wondering if this plan I outlined above make sense or is the optimal way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: I agree with @Trent. but why all these hassles? cant you do it in the database itself using SQL?

Comment: You can just export your db and remove unwanted rows through query it'll take upto 1 hr but if u started to write the scripts to do this it'll take upto 3-4 hrs depends on your tables

Comment: @bansi.  Their db file was built with powerbuilder so I cannot view their db file with phpmyadmin. Also I have to process the data before migrating to my tables

Comment: as far as i know Powerbuilder used to have a very nice Datawindow which can modify data, run SQLs and has ODBC connection capability to all major databases including MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

There is an data migration is possible in MySQL Workbench 6.0. I have migrated more than millions of record so this is not big deal.

Try 
http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/

[image]